# Amadeus API Points of interests did'nt work, status 500, error 38189

Tags: amadeus

I'm writing this topic, because when i try to connect to the Amadeus API to fetch points of interest, i got a status 500 with a code 38189.
There is the API response :
[API response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aefqR.png)

I'm using a production account, there is the request URL : https://api.amadeus.com/v1/reference-data/locations/pois?latitude=47.866844&longitude=3.493748&radius=20

Comment: Can you please check why your API doesn't work ?
We have bought a production account and we need this API for our school project

Comment: Hi Julien, few days ago, we opened an internal ticket to fix the issue. I will inform when the API is working again.

Comment: This is still a problem now.